# How to get data from a xml file into multiple string arrays in android?

Tags: android

Hi I am trying to get information from multiple string arrays held in a xml file to be output in a card view within a recycler view. I am thinking that I access the arrays through the adapter file for the recycler view, however I am not sure as I am new to this.

My xml file is called events.xml and is located in the res/values folder.

My adapter code is this:

```
public class EventCalenderAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EventCalenderAdapter.ViewHolder> {

String[] title;
String[] time_start;
String[] time_finish;
String[] date;

static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    CardView cardView;
    TextView titleView;
    TextView auxView1;
    TextView auxView2;
    TextView auxView3;

    public ViewHolder(CardView card) {
        super(card);
        cardView = card;
        titleView = (TextView) card.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        auxView1 = (TextView) card.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        auxView2 = (TextView) card.findViewById(R.id.text3);
        auxView3 = (TextView) card.findViewById(R.id.text4);
    }
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int i) {
    CardView v = (CardView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.event_task, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
    viewHolder.titleView.setText(title[i]);
    viewHolder.auxView1.setText(time_start[i]);
    viewHolder.auxView2.setText(time_finish[i]);
    viewHolder.auxView3.setText(date[i]);

}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return title.length;
}



}
```

Comment: You can ge the string by `String[] mydata = getResources.getStringArray(R.array.mystrings);`. Then you can pass it to the constructor of the adapter class and use it there. Read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Comment: @Raghunandan thank you for your comment however I get an error saying "Cannot resolve symbol 'getResources'"

Comment: you need to do that in a activity. Activity extends Context and getResources requires context

Comment: the other option is pass the context to the constructor of adapter class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your String arrays in constructor:

```
public EventCalenderAdapter(Context context){
   title= context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titleArray);
   //... get the rest of your arrays
}
```

Then when you instanciate your adapter (`new EventCalenderAdapter(YourActivity);` ), your arrays will be loaded.

Comment: should I put the constructor in the adapter class or the fragment that calls the class, sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: my fragment is now not working saying that EventCalenderAdapter(context) cannot be applied

Comment: Try with EventCalenderAdapter(getActivity());